# jQuery/Javascript - To run script function on itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following:

I have 2 `<div>`

```
<div class="panel-body">
    //some parent class for each textbox
    <input type="text" class="required" id="txtA"></input>
    <input type="text" class="required" id="txtB"></input>
    <button class="submitButton">A</button>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
    //some parent class for each textbox
    <input type="text" class="required" id="txtC"></input>
    <input type="text" class="required" id="txtD"></input>
    <input type="text" class="required" id="txtE"></input>
    <button class="submitButton">B</button>
</div>
```

and my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submitButton').click(function (e) {
        var errorLess = true;
        $(".TextError").remove();
        $(".required").each(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
                $('<span class=\"TextError\">This field is required!</span>').insertAfter(this);
                errorLess = false;
            }
        });
        return errorLess;
    });
});
```

How can I, in a way, validate only the fields in the div when the button contained, is clicked?

Meaning, when I click on button `A`, it will only validate `txtA` and `txtB`. When I click on button `B`, it will validate `txtC`, `txtD`, and `txtE`?

How do I have to modify the jQuery code in order for it to work this way?

Comment: use different `<form>`s for each.

Comment: `<textbox>` is not a valid HTML tag to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, I was rushing to type out to this question, I was actually writing in asp.net. My mind was filled with `<asp:TextBox>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` with selector `".panel-body"` to select the `.parentElement.parentElement` relative to current `.submitButton`. Set the `context` of `jQuery()` call where `".required"` is selector.

Not certain what the purpose of `$(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");` called within `.each()` loop?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submitButton').click(function (e) {
        var errorLess = true;
        $(".TextError").remove();
        var closestPanel = $(this).closest(".panel-body");
        $(".required", closestPaenl).each(function () {
            // $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
                $('<span class=\"TextError\">This field is required!</span>').insertAfter(this);
                errorLess = false;
            }
        });
        return errorLess;
    });
});
```

Comment: `Not certain what the purpose of $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error"); called within .each() loop?` I actually have more parents for each textbox, I just minimized the scale.

Comment: You can use `.closest()` with appropriate selector passed as parameter, then select descendants of the parent element. Why did you not include actual `html` using at Question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `<textbox>` is not a valid HTML Element. Refer full list of HTML Tags on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitButton').click(function(e) {
    var errorLess = true;
    $(".TextError").remove();
    $(this).parent().find('.required').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
        $('<span class=\"TextError\">This field is required!</span>').insertAfter(this);
        errorLess = false;
      }
    });
    return errorLess; {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-body">
  <!--//some parent class for each textbox-->
  <input type='text' class="required" id="txtA"></input>
  <input type='text' class="required" id="txtB"></input>
  <button class="submitButton">A</button>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <!--//some parent class for each textbox-->
  <input type='text' class="required" id="txtC"></input>
  <input type='text' class="required" id="txtD"></input>
  <input type='text' class="required" id="txtE"></input>
  <button class="submitButton">B</button>
</div>
```

From `$(this).parent()` will go to your parent element of clicked button. Then we simply find which elements has `.required` class by executing `.find('.required')`. If you'd like to run validation on them (assuming .required will only have for input tags) then we run a loop and see if they are empty or not. That's the code line you were looking for.